# Why is shallow binary tree better?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, tree, depth

Why do we always want shallow binary tree? In what cases is shallow binary tree better than non-shallow/minimum depth tree?

I am just confused as my prof keeps saying we want to aim for shallowest possible binary tree but I do not understand why. I guess smallar is better but is there any specific concrete reason? Sorry for my bad english thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is in regards to binary **search** trees - if not, please let me know and I can update this answer.

In a binary search tree, the cost of almost every operation (insertion, deletion, lookup, successor, predecessor, min, max, range search, split, join, etc.) depends on the height of the binary search tree. The reason for this is that these operations work by walking down the tree from the root until they either fall off the tree or find what they're looking for. The deeper the tree, the longer this can take if you get bad inputs.

By shuffling nodes around to keep the tree height low, we can make it so that these operations are, in general, very fast. A tree with height h can have at most 2<sup>h</sup> - 1 nodes in it, which is a huge number compared with h (figure that if h = 20, 2<sup>h</sup> - 1 is over a million!), so if you make an effort to pack the nodes into the tree higher up and closer to the root, you'll get better operation speeds all around.

There are some cases where it's actually beneficial to have trees that are as imbalanced as possible. For example, if you have a binary search tree and know in advance that some elements will be looked up more than others, you may want to shuffle the nodes around in the tree to put the high-frequency items higher up and the low-frequency items deeper in the tree. In non-binary-search-tree contexts, the randomized meldable priority queue works by randomly walking down a tree doing merges, and the *less* balanced the tree is the more likely it is for these operations to end early by falling off the tree.

Comment: hello guys, thank you. I meant just binary tree as that is what my professor keeps saying

Comment: Many of the same general rules above apply to arbitrary trees - the time spent walking in a tree depends on the tree depth, so shallow trees can be beneficial compared to deeper ones. But it's very situation-dependent, and if your instructor is talking about trees in general, I'd recommend asking them directly why that is.